# How to pause execution at the beginning of a dynamically added JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say we have a web-page that contains this inline-script:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://remote.com/external.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}());
</script>
```

As you can see, an external script, `external.js`, is appended to the page.

I would like to pause execution at the beginning of that external script. I am **not** able to edit that external script. (If I was, I'd just insert a `debugger;` statement at the top of that file.)

I am currently paused at this statement (of the above script):

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

There are no other SCRIPT elements on the page, so, if I resume execution, the next statement that is going to be executed will be the first statement of the external script.

How can I command Chrome's dev tools to pause execution at that next statement? A "Step over" command works only within the same call stack.

**Why I need this:** (This is just background. You don't need to read this.) W3C's HTML5 404 page contains a [script with a `fixBrokenLink` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/link-fixup.js) which is invoked on page load. This function then dynamically adds the [fragment-links.js](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fragment-links.js) script to the page. I'd like to step through that script. My goal is to understand how that script "fixes broken links". Of course, I could analyze that script statically, but I'd prefer to do it live, via the dev tools, by stepping through its code while it's being executed. I wouldn't bother asking this question if I didn't think it was possible.

---

## The solution:

In case it's not clear from the accepted answer, one merely has to step over the `document.body.appendChild(script);` statement, so that execution is paused at the closing brace `}` (see code above). At that point, Chrome will load the external script in the background, so that it will appear in the dev tools eventually. Once it does, one can set a break point in that script, and resume execution to that break point.

Comment: Opera's Dragonfly allows you to "[*Break on first statement of a new script*](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/debugger/)". I'd assume Chrome devtools have a similar option, don't they?

Comment: @Bergi OMG, OMG, OMG... testing right now...

Comment: Oh, c'mon, *you* really could statically analyze [that little script](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fragment-links.js), it does no magic :-) Valid question, though.

Comment: @Bergi I haven't event looked at that script yet `:)`. As soon as I noticed that I don't know how to pause its execution, it became all about figuring out how to do that, and if that's even possible. That script can be an one liner, like `'meh whatever';` for all I care.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but Dragonfly appears to allow stepping in into the next script, without setting any additional breakpoints.

Comment: You will need to press "Step Into" or "Step Over" to go to the next line, "Continue" continues to the next breakpoint (which would be the next script). Haven't used it often myself :-)

Comment: @Bergi Opera lets you step into the next JavaScript file. Chrome doesn't allow that. In Chrome, if you reach the end of one script, and then do a "Step over", execution will continue. In Opera though, execution will be paused at the first statement of the next script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is implemented now and you can turn on **Script First Statement** in the **Event Listener Breakpoints** under **Script** section.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. In the first script (here, `link-fixup.js`), add a breakpoint immediately *after* the `appendChild(script)` line. (So, here, on the close-bracket line at the end of `link-fixup.js`.)
2. Open the navigator in the Sources pane by clicking the top left corner of Devtools. You'll see the loaded script listed there once the browser completes loading the script.
3. In the navigator, open the loaded script (here, `fragment-links.js`) in the Sources pane and place a breakpoint in it.
4. Proceed to the breakpoint; you're done!

Comment: It's so easy. Somehow I thought that the browser's UI thread wouldn't allow the external script to load while JavaScript execution is paused.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

Look at the code and override one of the property accesses with `defineGetter`. I spoke with Pavel, the DevTools Lead and he recommended intercepting `window.jQuery` which is about the first JS line. It stores old jQuery value and you could `_defineGetter_` with `function() { debugger; return null; }`

See also:

- http://wordsbyf.at/2011/12/23/debugging-javascript-is-a-lame-title/ (Getters/Setters)
- and: https://gist.github.com/1676346

---

But while we're at it, can you [file a bug](http://crbug.com/new) that you want to be able to step into appendChild when it is about to eval JS? Also mention Opera's "Break on first statement of a new script" as that's really  handy. The Chrome DevTools eng team would like to give you nice support for this use case.

Comment: That's a creative approach. Luckily, the script *does* show up once you step over `appendChild(script)`, so I'm quite content with the current state. I filed the feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165781).

Answer (score 0):

This is not implemented yet as far as I know.
However you can vote for it or comment at dedicated bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156556

Comment: You seem to not have noticed, I created that ticket! `:)`